# Google Sheets IF THEN question

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have two columns of data, one column will have either "cc" or "cash" in each cell, the second column will have $amounts. I am trying to have it automatically know whether each dollar amount is associated with "cc" "cash" other words, whether "cc" or "cash" is in the cell next to the amount. I then would like it to fill the totals from "cash" and "cc" into specified cells.

Comment: Web Applications Stack Exchange is not a help desk. Please follow the [tour] to learn the ropes of this site.